# On the last selection validation is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my date of birth.

Basically, when input the first and second dob it's working fine but in the last selection year it's validating not working and return true.

Here is the code:

```js
    function dobvalidation()
{
    var dob1=document.getElementById('dob_input1').value;
    var dob2=document.getElementById('dob_input2').value;
    var dob3=document.getElementById('dob_input3').value;
    if(dob1=='' || dob1==null && dob2=='' || dob2==null && dob3=='' || dob3==null)
    {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-dob').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_dob_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_icon').style.marginLeft='-58px';
        document.getElementById('dob_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div id="headerErrorBox" style="display: none;">Error!</div>
<div id="dob_success_msg" style="display: none;">Success!</div>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input1"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option>DD</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">so on.. to 30</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_mm" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input2"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25%">
  <option>MM</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
  <option value="March">so on. untill dec</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input3"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option value="">YY</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `dob1=='' || dob1==null , dob2=='' || dob2==null , dob3=='' || dob3==null` It looks weird to have commas in that expression, shouldn't they be replaced by `||` as well?

Comment: @BlockCode I've fixed your MCVE for you. In future, please create a [mcve] so that we can more easily spot the error.

Comment: @Axnyff Post an answer; I think you've got it. (Though they should be `&&`, with brackets around `(dob1=='' || dob1==null)`.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 thanks bro. I am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Axnyff it's not working bro. I try to solve this but in the last input, it's giving the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your post to be more precise in what you're expecting? It looks like your code is buggy because of the commas but maybe it's something else.

Comment: @BlockCode Have you tried replacing `,` with `&&`? If not, and it works, Axnyff can write up an answer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes i did. but not working.

Comment: @BlockCode _What_'s not working?

Answer (score 1):

Change your last `<select>` tag name  `<select name="dob_day"...` to `<select name="dob_year"...` or   `<select name="whatever_you_want_to_name_it"...` but not the same `name=""` as it is already defined in the first `<select>` tag.

Edit:
 According to your JS function, this will return an empty value error in your last `<select>` tag.

```
<option value="">YY</option>
```

replace it with `<option>YY</option>`

Comment: This is definitely _a_ bug, but perhaps not _the_ bug. Could you copy the Stack Snippet into your answer and see if your change fixes the problem?

Comment: I assume that OP finds his answer !

Comment: It's don't effect the because class don't have concern with the class.

Comment: When you select **YY**, It will give you an empty error for sure!

Comment: but still not working I checked this input type text.. it's working but not selection.

Comment: ok post eveything in a fiddle, and paste a link here. @BlockCode

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should have **OR** instead of **AND**, so that if any value is not present it should return false.

```js
function dobvalidation()
{
    var dob1=document.getElementById('dob_input1').value;
    var dob2=document.getElementById('dob_input2').value;
    var dob3=document.getElementById('dob_input3').value;
    if(dob1=='' || dob1==null || dob2=='' || dob2==null || dob3=='' || dob3==null)
    {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div id="headerErrorBox" style="display: none;">Error!</div>
<div id="dob_success_msg" style="display: none;">Success!</div>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input1"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option>DD</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">so on.. to 30</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_mm" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input2"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25%">
  <option>MM</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
  <option value="March">so on. untill dec</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input3"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option value="">YY</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the values in selection DD and MM that's why it's not working.

```js
    function dobvalidation()
{
    var dob1=document.getElementById('dob_input1').value;
    var dob2=document.getElementById('dob_input2').value;
    var dob3=document.getElementById('dob_input3').value;
    if(dob1=='' || dob1==null , dob2=='' || dob2==null, dob3=='' || dob3==null)
    {
        document.getElementById('headerErrorBox').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('top-dob').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_error_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('below_error_dob_msg').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('dob_icon').style.marginLeft='-58px';
        document.getElementById('dob_success_msg').style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div id="headerErrorBox" style="display: none;">Error!</div>
<div id="dob_success_msg" style="display: none;">Success!</div>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input1"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option value=''>DD</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">so on.. to 30</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_mm" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input2"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25%">
  <option value=''>MM</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
  <option value="March">so on. untill dec</option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day" onchange="return dobvalidation()" id="dob_input3"  class="frmSelect" autocomplete="off" style="width: 30%;">
  <option value="">YY</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
</select>
```